# Angular 7 - how to style material menu to have items compacted closer to each other

Tags: html, css, angular, material-design

I am new to Angular and am wandering how to style a material design (MD) menus.
This menu would be intended mainly for a desktop app and should look something like menus in standard desktop apps (e.g. MS Excel).

I have searched the web but got no clear answers.

By default the Angular MD menu items are quite far apart - there is wide spacing between them. So they look like this (I am using text only for visualization here) :

```
Item A1

Item A2 >   Item A2-B1

Item A3     Item A2-B2

etc.        Item A2-B3 >     etc. 

            etc.
```

How can we override the MD default styles and reduce the menu buttons - smaller fonts, smaller size, no or minimal gaps, so we get a small compact menu with taking minimum real-estate and fitting more items in the menu - e.g:

```
Item A1
Item A2 >   Item A2-B1
Item A3     Item A2-B2 >     etc. 
etc.        Item A2-B3
```

Example menu.component.html file:

```
<div>
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" 
          class="myMenuItem">Menu</button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [class]="myMenu" > 
    <button mat-menu-item class="myMenuItem">Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item class="myMenuItem">Item 2</button>
  </mat-menu>
</div>
```

Would you please outline the styles and if there is a possibility to modify/configure MD default styles for the nav and button components to control their sizes and appearance, please provide instruction or link. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

if it is angular material menu component? And if you want to solve it by css ? then try it

```
.mat-menu-item{
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works with the combination of the answer from: Mihaylov

Comment: both `line-height` and `height` help you achieve this or as mentioned by @Mihaylov you can have `menu-item` as `flex` display and vertical align with align-items or align-content. Personally, I liked `line-height` as it is the single property and I need not worry about what other properties do

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way of styling mat-menu or its menu-items . It is just a showcase . Please use your own CSS that fits the exact needs of your desktop-like app. Hope I was helpful .

**menu.component.html**

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="myMenuItem">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [class]="myMenu" > 
  <button mat-menu-item class="myMenuItem">Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item class="myMenuItem"> Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

**menu.component.css**

```
.myMenu { 
  color : red;  

  padding: 0px ;
  margin : 0px; 
  height: auto; 

} 
.myMenuItem { 
  display:  flex;
  color : red;  
  font-size: 10px; 
  padding: auto ;
  margin : auto; 
  height: 30px; 
 align-content: center ; 
     align-items:  center ; 
     align-self: center ; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works - with the combination of the answer from: imon

Answer (score 0):

Using Mihaylov's answer as a starting point, I've come up with the following:

**styles.scss**

```
/*
  Tight Menu - A normal material menu but more compact
  Usage:
  <mat-menu class="tight-menu">
    <button mat-menu-item>Your Button</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Other Button</button>
  </mat-menu>
*/

.tight-menu .mat-menu-content {
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 4px !important;
}

.tight-menu button.mat-menu-item {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  height: 30px;
  align-items: center;
}
/* End of Tight Menu */
```